Python: web scraping a canvas populated with a script using Selenium/BS4
I am trying to implement a price tracking page to my Pyside6 application, and I want to do it by webscraping with Selenium and bs4.
My code enters a page of a website called Cardmarket, and now I am trying to implement webscraping of a chart showing the price fluctuations of a Yugioh Card.
The chart is a canvas and its data is filled in with a script and I'm having a hard time scraping anything about it; I tried:
1)Webscraping the info of the canvas
2)Trying to scrape the canvas as an image
3)Trying to webscrape
And all returned either an empty line or None
Here's the part of code I use:
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

from lxml import html 

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options



options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://www.cardmarket.com/it/YuGiOh")
print(driver.title)

'''WRITE IN THE SEARCHBAR'''
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "ProductSearchInput")))
search = driver.find_element(By.ID, "ProductSearchInput")
search.click()
search.send_keys("Ultimate conductor Tyranno")
search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#

'''TURN IT INTO GRILL VIEW'''
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "/html/body/main/section/div[2]/div[2]/div/a[2]")))
search = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/main/section/div[2]/div[2]/div/a[2]")
search.click()
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#


#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'h2.card-title.h3')))
search = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'h2.card-title.h3')
#attr = search.get_attribute()
i = 0
clickable_elements = []
for element in search:
    i += 1
    print(element.text)
    clickable_elements.append(element.text)


###User chooses one of the results###
'''choice = input("Choose one of the option, with a number between 1 and %i: " % i)'''
choice = 1  ##############################

while True:
    try:
        choice = int(choice)
        if choice == 0 or choice > i:
            raise Exception("That's not a valid option! retry: ")
        else:
            break

    except:
        print("That's not a valid option!")
        choice = input("Choose one of the option, with a number between 1 and %i: " % i)
#######################################

print(choice)
print(clickable_elements[choice - 1])
search = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/main/section/div[3]/div[%i]/a/div/h2" % int(choice))
search.click()

'''
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "chartjs-render-monitor")))
search = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'chart-init-script')
print(search.text)
'''

URL = driver.current_url
response = requests.get(URL) 
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "chart-init-script")))
script = soup.find('script')#, attrs = {'class':'chart-init-script'}) 
print(script.text)

I expected to either get the image of the chart, as google lets me download it like this:
(https://i.sstatic.net/cWEUHGog.png)
Or at least scrape what's contained in the script in order to give the data to a Pyside6 widget and fill it.
Here's the part of the HTML that I want to scrape:
(https://i.sstatic.net/kZEU1p2b.png)

Screenshots of the UI are great, screenshots of code or HTML are not. Please read why a screenshot of code/HTML is a bad idea. Edit your question and add the code/HTML as text, properly formatted.

To get price trend of single card you can use next example:
import json
import re

import pandas as pd
import requests

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:125.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/125.0"
}

# url of single card:
url = "https://www.cardmarket.com/it/YuGiOh/Products/Singles/Legacy-of-Destruction/Tenpai-Dragon-Fadra"
html_source = requests.get(url, headers=headers).text

labels, data = map(
    json.loads, re.search(r'"labels":(.*?]).*?data":(.*?])', html_source).groups()
)

df = pd.DataFrame({"time": labels, "price": data})
print(df)

Prints:
         time  price
0  20.04.2024   0.32
1  21.04.2024   0.31
2  22.04.2024   0.21
3  23.04.2024   0.21
4  24.04.2024   0.16
5  25.04.2024   0.20
6  26.04.2024   0.16
7  27.04.2024   0.16


Thank you for the help! Could I ask you to explain how this code works? why Json and Pandas? I don't know these libraries very well

@JustAMan You don't have to use pandas, I used it only to print nice table at the end. JSON - you should know this, it's data interchange format. This code just parses the required parts from HTML source and decodes it via json module.
